# How to learn arm TrustZone develop and use tee to get a goal?

Tags: arm, tee, trustzone

Im a new postgraduate,The teacher assigned content about using arm trustzone to develop secure and private computing and use tee, but I found very few trustzone development teaching videos on the Internet. How should I get started with trustzone development? Thank you for help.

I have:

1. An arm server to meet hardware requirements

expect:

1. Some videos about trustzone development
2. Let me master skills quickly about tee

Comment: Please read questions and answers in the tag [tag:trust-zone] and ask a question with more focus.  Tee by itself is just a concept, not even a concrete API, yet alone a framework.  Also look at the [tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/trust-zone/info).  The reason the duplicate has no good answer is, the question is not good.